# Core data - Check for null - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, attributes

On entering a new data into my core data for my given entity, how do I check if the entry for a particular attribute is null? 
I have three attribute 
name, mail and mailedCustomer. 
I add data as follows:

```
SalesPerson *data = (SalesPerson *)[NSEntityDescription         insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SalesPerson" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[data setName:name];
[data setEmail:userEmail];
 NSLog(@" mailed personel%@",data.mailedCustomer);
if([data.mailedCustomer != nil){
    NSLog(@"inside condition");
    [data setMailedCustomer:@"//"];
}
```

This doesn't work for me. Im trying to append some strings. So when I enter for the first time I need that attribute to be @"//" then append on further calls.

```
 NSLog(@" mailed personnel %@",data.mailedCustomer);
```

The above NSLog gives me:

```
  mailed personnel (null)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get what you want, your if statement is incorrect. You're now checking if it's NOT nil (meaning it has some value), and then you're resetting it to //. If you want it to be // and then append values, you have to check if it IS nil and then set it to //:

```
if (!data.mailedCustomer) {
    NSLog(@"inside condition");
    [data setMailedCustomer:@"//"];
}
```

Comment: That was a noobish question but u saved me some hair and time. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface NSObject (PE)
- (BOOL) isNull:(NSObject*) object;
- (BOOL) isNotNull:(NSObject*) object;
@end


@implementation NSObject (PE)

- (BOOL) isNull:(NSObject*) object {
    if (!object)
        return YES;
    else if (object == [NSNull null])
        return YES;
    else if ([object isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]) {
        return ([((NSString*)object) isEqualToString:@""]
                || [((NSString*)object) isEqualToString:@"null"]
                || [((NSString*)object) isEqualToString:@"<null>"]);
    }
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL) isNotNull:(NSObject*) object {
    return ![self isNull:object];
}

@end
















if([self isNotNull:some object])
{
not null
}
else
{
null
}
```

Comment: These would be better if static methods. That leads to [NSObject isNotNull:object] (instead of [object isNotNull:object]).